# Models overlapping in XNA 3.0

Tags: xna, 3d

I have to use XNA 3.0 for a class at school, and every solution to this problem I've found only works in XNA 4. I am rendering several 3D models, and the one that's drawn last is always on top. How do I make the depth decide this?

Comment: Have the same issue [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/186652/complex-mesh-created-in-blender-is-not-overlapping-when-rendered-in-monogame).
Have you found a solution?